# Prove that if a prime $p$ divides $5^n-2$ and $2^n-5$, then $p = 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

**The result below has been disproven.**

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that if a prime $p$ divides $5^n-2$ and $2^n-5$, then $p = 3$.

We know that $p \neq 2,5$. We need to have \begin{align*}5^n &\equiv 2 \pmod{p}\\2^n &\equiv 5 \pmod{p}.\end{align*} This gives us $10^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Thus $\text{ord}_{p}(10) \mid (n-1)$. How do we continue?

Comment: 11 minor edits in the span of 90 minutes is quite much, please think about it.

Comment: If it's correct concluding that $p\le7$, then observe that $2^3\equiv1\pmod{7}$, so $2^n\not\equiv5\pmod{7}$, for any $n$.

Comment: $p$ divides those quantities for all $n$? Or just for a fixed $n$?

Comment: I don't understand where you get $p\leq 7$ from.

Comment: This is a variant of a famous problem proposed by Schinzel, e.g. see A.S.Izotov, [On the prime divisors of $\,\gcd(3^{\large n}-2,2^{\large n}-3)$](http://www.fq.math.ca/Papers1/43-2/paper43-2-6.pdf). Do you have any reason to believe that this case is more elementary?  If not, you may be on a wild goose chase.

Comment: You do know that you are going in circles? Because you can derive your last expression just from $2^n\equiv5\pmod{p}$?

Comment: @user19405892 I don't understand your prior comment. What is the source of your question?

Comment: Why does $100 \equiv 2^{2(n+1)} \pmod{p}$ imply $10 \equiv 2^{n+1} \pmod{p}$?

Comment: Please don't change the question after you receive a counterexample in an answer. It will cause confusion, e.g. in prior comments addressing the original question.

Answer (score 18):

$\gcd(5^{65} - 2, 2^{65} - 5) = 12681 = 3^2 \cdot 1409$

Comment: I don't see why this is a proof. The statement says that given $n\in \mathbb{N}$, not for all $n$.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois I understood the statement to be about an arbitrary $n$, so I gave a counterexample. If $n$ is not arbitrary, then someone needs to specify which $n$ we are considering.

Comment: Now I understand what you did. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @MichaelBiro Does there exist $2 \mid n$ so $\gcd (2^n-5,5^n-2)>1$ ?

Comment: @ToanQuangPham $\gcd(2^{104}-5,5^{104}-2) = 1031$

Comment: @ToanQuangPham A possible interesting pattern - for even $n$ up to 20000, the only values the gcd takes is $1$ or $1031$. Weird.

Comment: @MichaelBiro Higher even that 20000 it seems.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by "the statement to be about an arbitrary $n$". Do you mean that the statement is about arbitrary **but fixed** $n$ (in that case I think that MonsieurGalois's comment still makes sense because, if I am not wrong then the phrase "the statement is about arbitrary **but fixed** $n$" is equivalent to the phrase "the statement is about **some** $n$")?

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for a counterexample  not found by trial and error with calculator (which I intend to find later) I have verified in Wolfram that $n=65$ (Michael Biro's answer) is the minimum possible value of $n$. However calculator Desmos gives the   wrong example $\color{blue}{\gcd(5^{54} - 2, 2^{54} - 5) = 4}$
  which would imply the counterexample $p=2$

[image]

In view of this, it would not be impertinent to check whether Wolfram's answer is correct. Is not it?

Comment: To be fair, I didn't double check the calculation. However, the numbers are not so large as to make a check infeasible, even by hand. 65 is nicely achievable by repeated squaring mod 1409.

Comment: Of course. I was referring to a formal aspect because if Desmos is wrong why not Wolfram? Have you seen Wolfram for $n$ till $65$?

Answer (score 0):

Proof that $1409 \mid \gcd(5^{65}-2,2^{65}-5$):

We have \begin{align*}5^5 &\equiv 307 \pmod{1409}\\5^{10} &\equiv 1255 \pmod{1409}\\5^{20} &\equiv 1172 \pmod{1409}\\5^{40} &\equiv 1218 \pmod{1409}\\5^{65} &\equiv 2 \pmod{1409}\end{align*} and \begin{align*}2^{12} &\equiv 1278 \pmod{1409}\\2^{24} &\equiv 253 \pmod{1409}\\2^{48} &\equiv 604 \pmod{1409}\\2^{60} &\equiv 1189 \pmod{1409}\\2^{65} &\equiv 5 \pmod{1409}.\end{align*}

Comment: It suffices to check one - the other is just the $65$th power because $\,x^{\large 65}\,$ is self-inverse mod $p=1409\,$ by $\ \color{#c00}{65^2\equiv1}\pmod{p-1},\,$ i.e.  $\,1408 = 128\cdot 11\mid 65^{\large 2}-1 = 64\cdot 66.\,$ This implies that $\,\left[2^{\large \color{#c00}{65}}\!\equiv 5\right]^{\large\color{#c00}{ 65}}\!\!\Rightarrow\, 2\equiv 5^{\large 65}\ \ $